# speed up query with a lot of like clauses

Tags: mysql

I have a dockets table which has many entries. I already added an index to the foreign key of entries with key type of "MUL". But the queries still run slow because I have to check 2 columns for each row to check if they do not contain any of 4 keywords. That means I have 8 NOT LIKE clauses for this one query:

```
SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries` 
WHERE `entries`.`docket_id` IN (1, ...) 
AND (column1 NOT LIKE '%Keyword1%' AND column2 NOT LIKE '%Keyword1%') 
AND (column1 NOT LIKE '%Keyword2%' AND column2 NOT LIKE '%Keyword2%') 
AND (column1 NOT LIKE '%Keyword3%' AND column2 NOT LIKE '%Keyword3%') 
AND (column1 NOT LIKE '%Keyword4%' AND column2 NOT LIKE '%Keyword4%')
```

Is there anything else I can do to speed up this query besides adding the index to the foreign key, which I have already done.

Comment: wildcard likke struggle to use the index anyway, Is this MyISAM ? May be worth adding a full text index ?

Comment: if you are on >5.6 you can add FULLTEXT on innodb also.But do you really need all those like?Maybe db normalization can help

Comment: @exussum I am using InnoDB and version is 5.6.

Comment: MySQL cannot use any indexes on column1 or column2.  It could if you were doing `LIKE 'Keyword1%'`.  Since MySQL cannot use the indexes, it must check every row in the table to find the match.  Read more here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning

Comment: @AndyLester is fulltext search a viable solution?

Comment: No index is going to help if you start with %.  You do know those parens do nothing.  (A and B) and (C and D)  same as A and B and C and D.   That is just an odd search.  What is the business need behind it?   There has to be a better design.

Comment: What does how websites work have to do with this messed up situation?  Name one website where you filter on 4 not wildcards?   -1

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to check that way, create a keywords table. Only two columns, the id from the entries table, and the keyword. Then check that table, except you don't need to do the likes, you can do an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

Per Andy, this will *not* make it faster. However, it may help determine that the `NOT LIKE` statements are not the slow down culprit. I haven't tested this, but try something like this:

```
SELECT `entries`.* FROM `entries` 
WHERE `entries`.`docket_id` IN (1, ...) 
  AND (
     column1 NOT REGEXP '.*keyword1.*|.*keyword2.*|.*keyword3.*|.*keyword4.*'
     AND 
     column2 NOT REGEXP '.*keyword1.*|.*keyword2.*|.*keyword3.*|.*keyword4.*'
  )
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: Regexes aren't going to speed it up.  The problem is that mysql cannot use any indexes for the matching, and must check every row for a match.

Comment: You're right. You should post that as an answer. If anything, this answer will prove to Donato that it isn't the `NOT LIKE` statements that are slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot use any indexes on `column1` or `column2`. It could if you were doing `LIKE 'Keyword1%'`. Since MySQL cannot use the indexes, it must check every row in the table to find the match.

Read more here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning